# x509 Authentication with CAS Single Sign On loops

Tags: single-sign-on, x509certificate, cas

I'm using CAS for single sign on with x509 certificates. The initial app that users attempt to access gets into a loop where it keeps calling /cas/login?service=https:///myapp.

Comment: I'm suspecting the cookie may not be sent with the requests.  I'll start logging the cookies to verify.

Comment: Problem solved: It was requesting a resource that wasn't there.